# Infragistics version 2010 compatibility

Tags: .net, infragistics

I am using Infragistics version 8.1 in my project. I heard that now the latest version availble is 2010. I just want to know that if i use Infragistics 2010 in my project will it be compatible, because in my project I am using .net 2.0. If I upgrade, what will be the compatibility?

thank you

Comment: Without giving more details about your project you're never going to get an answer to this question. I'd advise looking through the changelogs on the infragistic webpage and make this decision yourself. If you aren't sure and you don't absolutely need it, at least make a copy of the codebase and make sure that you're okay with rolling back your code afterwards if/when it breaks everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Infragistics controls in 2010.1 and 2010.2 are still compiled against .NET Framework 2.0. So you don't need to worry about that.

You should worry about breaking changes they have made (I can remember one in UltraCombo regarding the AutoComplete, where the old property was replaced by a new one, and after upgrading the new property had the default value, which I think was "No AutoComplete").

Answer (score 0):

I have no issues at all using the 2010 versions with Win forms projects in both .net 2 and 3 vintages.

Use the Project upgrade utility and you will be fine.  Of course let it make a back up just in case.